# PHP Ignoring if else statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an if statement for retrieving the lat and long from an address and insert it into a sql database. I have the basic structure of the form working but wish to include empty field checking and pregmatch but if i try an enter more else if statements the nothing happens.

```
// Your Google Maps API key
$key = "key";
// Desired address
$address = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='.$location.'&output=json&oe=utf8&sensor=false&key=$key';
// Retrieve the URL contents
$data = file_get_contents($address);
// Parse the returned XML file
$jsondata = json_decode($data,true); 
if (is_array($jsondata )&& $jsondata ['Status']['code']==200){ 
  $lat = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][0]; 
  $lon = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][1];
}
elseif (mysql_query("INSERT INTO database (type, category, suggest, title, url, description, phone, fax, facebookpage, twitterpage, busemail, number, streetAddress, city, state, zip, country, name, email, latitude, longitude) 
VALUES ('$type', '$category', '$title', '$url', '$description', '$phone', '$fax', '$facebookpage', '$twitterpage', '$busemail', '$number', '$streetAddress', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$country', '$name', '$email', '$lat', '$lon')");     {
die( header ("Location: http://www.exampleerrorpage.com" ) . mysql_error());
}
else { mail( $email, "Subject", $message, $headers );
header( "Location: http://www.examplecomplete.com/" );
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit only have basic knowledge in php and am still very much a newbie. Be Gentle. Thanks again.

EDIT - The address portion of the form my not always be there. So the geocode does not always need to execute.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  Please explain, with code, what it is that you're trying, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: excuse me? How is it ignoring? If will be executed if condition is `TRUE`, otherwise `ELSE` will be executed. So, if ELSE is not being executed, is because it was run IF statement.

Comment: PHP is *never* "ignoring" anything. You simply have a logic error, which we can't help you with since you're only showing us the non-errord version.

Comment: I don't see "else" mentioned anywhere at all in the code? please give an example of the code not working.

Comment: And there is no else branch anyway...

Comment: Show the code you tried that isn't working.

Comment: you don't need  the else. just place the mysql_query statement inside the if

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you want and comment where it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slowly go through your logic again and think. Your programs says:

> If *the JSON data is valid*, set the two variables `$lat` and `$lon`,
>   else (if the JSON data is not valid but) if *the SQL query returns `true`*, `die` with an error,
>   else (if none of the above), send an email.

You simply have a very screwed up *if-then-else* logic.

Logic-wise, you probably want something along the lines of:

```
if (/* JSON data not valid */) {
    die('Error');
}

$lat = ...;
$lon = ...;

// Prevent SQL injection!
$lat = mysql_real_escape_string($lat);
$lon = mysql_real_escape_string($lon);

$query = "INSERT INTO ...";
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

if (!mail(...)) {
    die('Error sending mail');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might seem dumb but make yourself some way to see if the query just always falls in the if (your if always returns true.)

If it is, check your if statement. I don't see any other way it would not get in the else exept if your statement is always returning true (something like 1==1)

If you want your statement to always return false, just add &1!=1 to your statement. It should then always get in the else part of things.